# Rollup plugin develop: How to prevent other plugins processing files those my plugin have already processed

Tags: javascript, bundle, rollup, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-postcss

I am developing a rollup plugin to process a part of plugin-user's project files (js, sass, css etc) with some tricks, but if user have another plugin in his or her project such as postcss, it will reprocessed files which my plugin already processed, and cause error.

So I want to know is there a common way to mark files which have already processed by my plugin and remove it from rollup build chain so that other plugin can't load and process it.

I can't find any useful info in rollup wiki...